# blinking jquery cycle plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, internet-explorer-9, cycle

jQuery cycle plugin for a moment displays all images that are loaded into it in a column when the page is loaded, and my client claims that this is only in IE9. Is there a way of fixing it?

Comment: Could you not hide the column using CSS and then only make it visible once the cycle plugin has fully loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the delay to load the plugin. I usual fix this with some css. Create a div around the slideshow and set the css to, this will solve your problem.

```
#boxaroundslideshow {
    overflow:hidden; // this is important as it will lose the scrollbars
    display:block;
    width:widthofslideshow;
    height:heightofslideshow;
}
```